# How to solve this incomplete elliptic equation in Matlab? Thank you!

Tags: matlab, computer-algebra-systems, elliptic-integrals

I am trying to solve this formula in Matlab $$V= \frac{ 2r_{1}r_{2}^{2}k^{2}}{3}(2 \bullet R_{f} (0,1-k^{2},1) - \frac{1+k^{2}}{3} R_{d}(0,1-k^{2},1)$$
where $k = \frac{r_{1}}{r_{2}}$

I thought it was the code below but when I put the value in it comes out with 1.6296 when I put in $r_{1} = 0.5$ and $r_{2} = 1.5$, I know the answer is 0.5807496. Please help, I don't know what I have done wrong. Thank you so much in advance!

code:

```
close all


clear all


clc

prompt='Enter r1: ';


r1=input(prompt);


prompt='Enter r2: ';


r2=input(prompt);


k=r1/r2;


for b=1:length(r1)


    for c=1:length(r2)


for y=0:length(1-k.^2)


    Rf=y;


    Rd=y;


v=(2.*Rf-((1+k.^2)/3).*Rd);



plot(v,'LineWidth',2);


    end


        end


    end


display(v);
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with [tag:coding-theory].  Also [tag:elliptic-equation] means that the question should be about certain types of partial differential equations. Please read tag descriptions before randomly adding them to a question.

Comment: Is there actually an elliptic integral in here (like calculating the arc length of some ellipse or...)?

Comment: Also, debugging Matlab snippets is off-topic.

Comment: Yes the elliptic integral is in Carlsons symmetric form

Comment: its calculating the volume of intersecting cylinders